# Is there a way to run Stripe CLI on a build server?

Tags: stripe-payments

In order to use stripe CLI you have to open a browser and log in.
I want to run tests on a build server, is there a way to authenticate without logging in using a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Co-der yes you can either use `stripe config` [1] to set your testmode API keys on the build server, or pass the `--api-key <key>` argument in your calls.

You can create restricted keys from your Stripe dashboard that are specific to CI or just use your testmode publishable and secret keys.

You might set your API keys something like this:

```
stripe config --set test_mode_api_key sk_test_xxx
stripe config --set test_mode_publishable_key pk_test_yyy
```

[1] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/wiki/config-command